# Jquery Daterangepicker Date Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, daterangepicker

I have a daterangepicker with the code below.

I want to change the format of the date but it's not working. The date in the textbox still is of the format *mm/dd/yyyyy*.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datep').daterangepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        singleDatePicker: false,
        calender_style: "picker_1",
    }, function (start, end, label) {
        $.ajax({
            url : "{!! action('OrderController@orderlistdata') !!}",
            data : "stardate="+start.toISOString()+"&enddate="+end.toISOString()
        }).done(function(result){
            $("#tbody").html(result);
            oTable.reload();
        });
    });
});
```

Am I typing a wrong code?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [daterangepicker.com](http://www.daterangepicker.com/), it appears that the [option](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options) `locale` will work for this, since there is no `dateFormat` option... For example:

```
$('.datep').daterangepicker(
{
    locale: {
      format: 'YY-MM-DD'
    },
    singleDatePicker: false,
    //... other options...
})
```

See a demonstration of this below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datep').daterangepicker({
    locale: {
      format: 'YY-MM-DD'
    },
    singleDatePicker: false,
    calender_style: "picker_1",
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log('start: ', start, 'end: ', end, 'label: ', label);
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />Date:
<input class="datep" />
```